# Understanding notation in the paper "Sparse Sinkhorn Attention"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm reading the paper [Sparse Sinkhorn Attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11296) by Tay, Yi, et al. and am confused on some of the notation used in **Section 3**.

At the start of the section, the authors describe block-based attention and introduce a few variables:

> In our method,
> the input sequence $X$ of length $\ell$ is partitioned into $N_b$
> blocks in which each block has a length of $b$ tokens.

Later on, they define the block-wise pooling operation in **Equation 2** as follows:

[image]

If my understanding is correct, it seems they are now using $N_B$ instead of $N_b$ to indicate the number of blocks, and are using $\ell_{B}$ instead of $b$ to indicate the number of tokens in each block. Is this just an inconsistency in the notation, or am I overlooking something?

Thanks in advance for any insights!